# How to change the resolution time calculation in JIRA?

Tags: project-management, jira, kanban

Is it possible to change the resolution time calculation to start not with the issue creation time, but rather with the time when an issue was transferred into a certain state?

The use case is as follows - We use a kanban-ish development method, where we create most issues/featues/stories in a backlog upfront; thus, this kills the usefulness of the resolution time gadget. In our case, the lead/resolution time should rather be calculated using the time where an issue has been pulled to the selected issues.

As this calculation is the basis for multiple gadgets, maybe it could be changed per gadget in order to avoid unforeseen issues with other gadgets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a service level management tool SLAdiator (http://sladiator.com) which calculates resolution / reaction times based on the duration that ticket has spent in a certain status (or statuses). You can view these tickets online as well as get reports.

Comment: Thanks, mkemme. Looks very promising. I was losing hope :) I'll evaluate and respond.